# values are populating with 2 only

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I'm a newbie to java & I'm trying to read numeric data from a text file & I want to write each number in a separate cell in an Excel spreadsheet.

Input data is as below:(abc.txt)

> 3008,45,14,277,10,6371,223,208,116,3036,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,‌​0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2 2893,114,16,108,30,5066,245,223,102,4340,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0‌​,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2

I want each value in a different cell. I'm using Apache POI for using excel sheets. This is what I'm able to code till now
    package com.example.practise;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
//import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Creationhelper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;


public class MultivariateDT {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/419803/Desktop/abc.txt"));
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/419803/Desktop/workbook.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
        Row row = null;
        Cell cell = null;
        String line = null;

        String delimiter = ",";

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            String[] temp=null;
            String str = " ";
            temp = line.split(delimiter);

            for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
            {
                str = temp[i] + str;

                int rownum;
                for (rownum =0; rownum < 100; rownum++)
                {
                    row = sheet1.createRow(rownum);

                    for (int cellnum =0; cellnum <temp.length; cellnum ++)
                    {
                        cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
                        cell.setCellValue(temp[i]);        
                    }

                } 
            }

            System.out.println();

        }
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

No.of rows & cells that have to be created are correct, but data in excel file is wrong.
In excel file only showing 2,2,2,2 so on.

Can any one please help me??

Answer (score 0):

I think you have too many for-loops with which you are iterating too much, i.e. first you loop over all items in the line, for these you create 100 rows and in each row you iterate overa all items in the line again, creating rows, bug in setCellValue() you are using temp[i], not temp[cellnum], so you are first creating 100 rows with temp[0], then 100 rows with all temp[1], ...

It depends on how the resulting spreadsheet should look like, but I would try to adjust the for-loops accordingly, e.g. for one row per line you would remove the outer too for-loops, for 100 rows per line you would remove the single outer for-loop.

Comment: can u help me with some solution?

Comment: sorry, but I do not know what exactly you are trying to do and thus it is hard to suggest more, it really depends on the program logic that you are trying to achieve and how you then use the for()-loops accordingly.